# HTML/CSS: Is it possible to make a table that can have its column selected?

Tags: html, css

It's kinda difficult to explain what I want to achieve (and feel free to modify the title if you can think of a better one), so I'll give you an example:

```
 Street: First Lane
         South side 28
   City: Duckburg
Country: Disneyland
    ZIP: 1234567890-XY
```

This is what I want the user to see. But I also want the user to be able to select only the right column, so he can copy-paste the contents of it elsewhere. If I do this with a table, the user can only select whole rows, and a copy-paste operation will copy row headers as well. If I do this with two separate containers next to each other, the labels get out of synch with the contents if some item has more than one line.

Can this be achieved somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Try something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        #left_side { float: left; text-align: right;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="left_side">
            Street:<br><br>
            City:<br>
            Country:<br>
            ZIP:
        </div>
        <div id="right_side">
            First Lane<br>
            South side 28<br>
            Duckburg<br>
            Disneyland<br>
            1234567890-XY
        </div>
    </div>      
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This becomes nonsense without visual CSS being applied. Anything that handles the data in a linear fashion (such as a search engine or screen reader) will get the labels one after the other before any of the address arrives.

Comment: Neither is important in my case - this is for a HTML formatted email. If google gets to indexing this, that will mean a serious security hole somewhere. :D However, this way requires me to check each item to see how many lines it has. Possible of course, but I'd rather prefer something more elegant.

Comment: Emails are more likely to be read in a linear fashion — people still use screen readers with email, people view email in plain text mode, email clients often have poor support for CSS, etc, etc.

Comment: Well, you never sad why do you need it :)
Since email readers do have poor support for CSS, I would suggest you go with your initial, table based, solution.

Comment: Well, true, I didn't say it. And it seems to me that the broader question is more interesting too. So I won't modify it, although I might end up with lots of unusable answers in this way. :P

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

Use [YUI datatable](http://www.developer.yahoo.com/yui/datatable). It works even with JQuery.

Although this sample use row selection you can use column selection

You can use any input format including JSON, HTML table, XML and text. No input field required. I use somenting like

[App http://img74.imageshack.us/img74/1833/singled.gif](http://img74.imageshack.us/img74/1833/singled.gif)

According to above, when i click (yes, mouse click) a single row, it will be highlighted (selected) and supported actions will be applied (Edit). Supported actions will be applied according to your business requirement

In your case, a HTML table, you set up according to (You can test it if you want):

First lets set up CSS and JavaScript

```
<!-- Combo-handled YUI CSS files: --> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/combo?2.7.0/build/paginator/assets/skins/sam/paginator.css&2.7.0/build/datatable/assets/skins/sam/datatable.css"> 
<style type="text/css">
    .center {text-align:center;}
</style>
<!-- Combo-handled YUI JS files: --> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/combo?2.7.0/build/yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js&2.7.0/build/connection/connection-min.js&2.7.0/build/element/element-min.js&2.7.0/build/paginator/paginator-min.js&2.7.0/build/datasource/datasource-min.js&2.7.0/build/datatable/datatable-min.js&2.7.0/build/json/json-min.js"></script>
```

Our body (generated on server side)

```
<body class="yui-skin-sam">
    <div id="container">
        <table id="source">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>AAA</th>
                    <th>BBB</th>
                    <th>CCC</th>
                    <th>HIDDEN</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>a</td>
                    <td>b</td>
                    <td>c</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>a</td>
                    <td>b</td>
                    <td>c</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>a</td>
                    <td>b</td>
                    <td>c</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="actionContainer">
        <a id="action" href="#">Edit row</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

Now lets configure script after body (code commented)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var settings = {
        widgetList:{
            reference:null,
            datatable:{
                columnSettings:[
                    // key attribute matches key attribute in dataSource fields attribute - see bellow
                    {key:"AAA", label:"A custom label"},
                    // if label is omitted, default to key value
                    // className customizes a class to apply to a column
                    {key:"BBB", className:"center"},
                    {key:"CCC"},
                    // i do not want to show id value, so i hide it through hidden attribute
                    {key:"HIDDEN", hidden:true},
                    // i want to generate a custom value regardless dataSource, so i set up a custom formatter function - see below
                    {key:"CUSTOM", label:"A custom value", formatter:customValue}
                ],
                settings:{
                    selectionMode:"single"
                }    
            }, // eof datatable
            dataSource:{
                // use $("#source")[0] whether you use JQuery (do not forget set up JQuery)
                // source points to data that will populate our datatable
                // in our case data will be retrieved from a HTML table
                // see responseType bellow
                source:YAHOO.util.Dom.get("source"),
                settings:{
                    responseSchema:{
                        fields:[
                            // key attribute matches th content 
                            {key:"AAA"},
                            {key:"BBB"},
                            {key:"CCC"},
                            {key:"HIDDEN"}],
                        // set up input
                        responseType:YAHOO.util.DataSource.TYPE_HTMLTABLE
                    }
                }
            }, // eof dataSource
            create:function() {
                this.reference = new YAHOO.widget.DataTable("container", this.datatable.columnSettings, new YAHOO.util.DataSource(this.dataSource.source, this.dataSource.settings), this.datatable.settings);
            } // eof create 
        }  // eof widgetList
    }; // eof setting

    // sets up custom value
    function customValue(container, record, column, data) {
        // container references a cell
        container.innerHTML = record.getData("AAA") + " - " + record.getData("BBB") + " - " + record.getData("CCC") + " - " + record.getData("HIDDEN");
    }

    (function() {
        // use $("#actionContainer").set("display", "none"); in JQuery
        YAHOO.util.Dom.setStyle("actionContainer", "display", "none");

        settings.widgetList.create();

        // RIA applications
        YAHOO.util.Event.addListener("action", "click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var datatable = settings.widgetList.reference;
            var recordArray = datatable.getRecordSet().getRecords();

            for(var i = 0; i < recordArray.length; i++) {
                if(datatable.isSelected(recordArray[i])) {
                    alert("You have selected id: " + recordArray[i].getData("HIDDEN") + "\nYou can use a JQuery dialog to collect data changes");
                }
            }
        });  

        // rowClickEvent - use subscribe
        settings.widgetList.reference.subscribe("rowClickEvent", function(args) {
            // args.target is a Record instance
            if(this.isSelected(args.target)) {
                this.unselectRow(args.target);

                YAHOO.util.Dom.setStyle("actionContainer", "display", "none");
            } else {
                this.unselectAllRows();

                this.selectRow(args.target);

                YAHOO.util.Dom.setStyle("actionContainer", "display", "block");
            }
        });
    })();
</script>
</html>
```

Minimal changes are required if you use JSON, XML or text. Feel free to ask for them.

In order to use column selection use columnClickEvent instead.

regards,

Comment: OMFG! And all this for a tiny HTML-formatted email which otherwise will have only one more line of text in it! O_O I'll pass, thank you!

Comment: You can extend Yahoo datatable in order to set up specific feature. It is a powerfull component that solves any question when the subject is HTML table. I use it successfully.

Comment: It does seem powerful indeed, and I'm sure that many people will find this answer useful. :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you have all of the right hand column of your example in 1 cell somehow? That way it would be all selected together.

The row headers would stay aligned as long as the number of rows in each part of the address was always the same.

Comment: Do you mean the same as Krule's answer? If so, check my comment to it.